# In the Bailey School Kids, do we ever find out if any of the adults actually are the supernatural creatures the kids think they are?

Tags: bailey-school-kids

You''ll know the basic plot arc of the Bailey School Kids if you've ever read any of them. If you haven't, from Wikipedia:

> In each story, the Bailey School kids encounter a relatively innocuous character (such as a school teacher, custodian, etc.) who may or may not be a mythical being (e.g. a vampire, werewolf, dragon, etc.). The reader is left guessing whether the innocuous character is the said mythical being or not.

Is this universally true in every story? Or is there any stories where the kids confirm that the said adult is said creature?

Comment: From what I can tell, that's literally the joke

Comment: A few times. I think it happened in Giants Don't Go Snowboarding.

Comment: @AaronGullison care to expand that into an answer?

Comment: @AaronGullison - The ending seems ambiguous. There was certainly a large beanstalk but they never confirmed if the giant was a real giant; https://i.stack.imgur.com/tABbI.png

Comment: @Valorum a large beanstalk more or less confirms it, IMHO.

Comment: @TheAsh - It's certainly not something you see every day, that's for sure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Yes, no, maybe.

I asked my good friend Debbie Dadey this question. Apparently in the first book the authors (she and Marcia T. Jones) wanted to have a final chapter that revealed Mrs. Jeepers as a genuine vampire. Their editor nixed the idea and this seems to have set the stage for all of the subsequent books.

> **Q:** *Are any of the adult in the Bailey School Kids books ＊actually＊ supernatural? Or is it always deliberately left unstated?*
>
> **Debbie Dadey:** *When Marcia and I wrote the first book, Mrs. Jeepers was definitely a vampire. Our editor asked us to change it to
> make it not so scary*
>
> <sub><sup>[Via Twitter](https://twitter.com/DebbieDadey/status/990717469840105472)</sup></sub>

Comment: Wow, boo on the editors.